# Round... or flat?

Tags: word, wordplay

> With 6 I'm round.
> With 5 I'm flat.
> With 4 I'm round.
> With 3 I'm flat.

What 6-letter word am I?

Comment: This deserves more attention IMO. +1

Comment: @Tacoタコス I appreciate it, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are

> PLANET  ->  6 letters and despite skeptics, round/spherical

with 5

> PLANE  -> a plane is a flat surface

with 4

> PLAN (as suggested by the OP)  -> a plan can be well-rounded
>  but not PANE, my original guess ->  a window can have a round pane, but not sure on this

with 3

> PAN  -> a pan is flat, and a pancake is the poster child for flatness

Comment: 4 could also be PLAN, but not sure how this would work either

Comment: I love this answer! I hope it's correct lol

Comment: @riskymysteries that's some lateral thinking! Perhaps the [tag:lateral-thinking] tag would be a good fit here?

Comment: Personally, I would find applying "well-rounded" to the four-letter word distinctly unnatural-sounding. It's not a construction I would use.

Comment: someone show this guy an appam pan... jk good answer